# difference between inactive and free memory in output of FreeBSD top utility?

Tags: freebsd, memory, top

`top -d1` displays following SDRAM usage statistics on one of my older machines:

```
125M Active, 42M Inact, 51M Wired, 17M Cache, 34M Buf, 2720K Free
```

In total, there is 256MiB of memory installed. According to `top` manual, `Inact` is number of inactive bytes and `Free` is number of free bytes. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

`Inactive` is memory that was used by processes that are no longer running, but is cached since it may be used again. `Free` is completely free and ready to use memory.